# From UITableView to custom view

Tags: uitableview, ios4

I have made a UITabelView that works nice, but when i now press a link I would like it to go to a new View, which should be different depending on the link choosen. How can i do that? If there is a nice tutorial it whould be nice.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you be more clear.What exactly you want to do?where is the link, in table row?

Comment: Yes, i would like to show a picture when a cell in the table is pressed, is it posible to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `UITableViewDelegate`'s method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and there display a picture.

Comment: Thanks i found out, now i would like to implement pageControl. But i find it difficult, how could i upload the code, so that you could see it?

Comment: Edit initial question or create new one.

Comment: I found out, sorry for me being new on this forum. Thanks for the help so far.